# breaking down an expression into partial fractions

Tags: infinite, series

I am trying to find the limit of an infinite series given as
`1/(n^2-1)`
I came across the following general term of the sequence of partial sums
`3/4-(1/2n)-1/(2(n+1)`
I would appreciate assistance to understand how this expression is arrived at.
I have tried breaking down the original expression into partial fractions, but cannot get to the given result.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Perhaps you wanted [the math site](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right forum